# How to call the output of a function in another function?

Tags: r

I have two functions:

```
getTotalBL <- function(Ne, n){
  ...
  total_branch_length #output
}


getSNPnumber <- function(total_branch_length,mu,L){


}
```

Where the `total_branch_length` in `getSNPnumber` is the output of the first function (`getTotalBL`)
Do I need to do something more than write the same name of the output or is it correct this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the output of `getTotalBL` in an object and pass that on as a function argument to `getSNPnumber`. The scope of `total_branch_length` is restricted to `getTotalBL`.

Here are two examples to demonstrate:

**Possibility 1:**

```
f1 <- function(x) x^2;
f2 <- function(xsquared, b) xsquared + b;

f2(f1(2), 1)
#[1] 5
```

which is the same as

```
ret_from_f1 <- f1(2);
f2(ret_from_f1, 1);
#[1] 5
```

**Possibility 2:**

We can also have a function as an argument of another function (here `f2`):

```
f2 <- function(fct, x, b) fct(x) + b;
f2(f1, 2, 1) 
#[1] 5
```

Comment: Thank youuuuuu so much !

Answer (score 1):

If all you're interested in is transferring the results from one function into another, I'd like to suggest the `%>%` function; it lets you pipe/chain results from one command into another.

It's available in packages `magrittr` (or`dplyr` if you're already using `tidyverse`).

**Reusing the above 'Possibility 1'**

```
f1 <- function(x) x^2;
f2 <- function(xsquared, b) xsquared + b;

require(dplyr)
f1(2) %>% f2(1)
```

**UPDATE: Why `%>%` is useful**

To my extremely limited knowledge, R stores all objects in RAM. When you create objects, only for them to be removed, they are still created in RAM. Using `%>%` lets you bypass this.