# Duckworth-Lewis-Stern calculator to calculate the revised target

Tags: r, calculator

With the Cricket World Cup going on, I wanted to create a Duckworth-Lewis calculator of my own for One Day Internationals using R.

This is a challenge I assigned myself, to push myself in understanding more on R, and what I could do. Duckworth-Lewis is an algorithm used in cricket when unexpected delays (notably bad weather) takes centre stage. The algorithm (in One Day Internationals) involves calculating Team 2's Par Score, which is where 'Team 2 Target' equals 'Team 1 Score' times the quotient of 'Team 2 Resources' and 'Team 1 Resources', and we add 1 to find the target (otherwise it creates room for a South Africa 2003 World Cup scenario).

```
team2_target = function(team1_score, team1_resources, team2_resources) {
  return((team1_score * (team2_resources/team1_resources) + 1)
}
```

I want to make my function use the number of wickets lost, as well as the overs remaining to calculate the 'Team 2 Resources' variable. For example, if Team 1 scored 277 out of its full 50 overs and Team 2 scored 240, with the loss of 4 wickets after 40 overs, I want to be able to use the 'Overs' and 'Wickets Lost' as variables. It sounds really simple, but both these factors matter, and if either of my desired variables change, the team2_resources variable itself will change.

Comment: To those that want access to the Duckworth-Lewis-Stern table, here is my GitHub https://github.com/asekhar177/Duckworth-Lewis-Stern .

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You're on the right track. You probably need another function that calculates the `team2_resources` variable for you. Then you can use the output of that function as an input to your `team2_target` function. This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751566/how-to-call-the-output-of-a-function-in-another-function

Comment: Also to give some clarity how I want my calculator to work: http://wicklowcountycricket.com/duckworth-lewis-calculator/ .

Comment: Are you actually trying to look up some value for `team2_resources` from some other table? Or what is the formula for calculating the `team2_resources` variable based on the number of wickets lost and the number of overs left? If you can specify the formula, we can help you write the function.

Comment: Hahaha now that's where the trouble starts. I was trying to read the Excel file I created in my GitHub, particularly if there is some way to calculate the ```team2_resources``` variable. Just now I found something (just give me a tick)!

Comment: Here's a file to read: http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~tim/papers/twenty20.pdf . Although this discusses about Twenty20 cricket, I was wanting to use that formula in that file for One Day Internationals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you need.

First I use a function to look up team 2's resources from your excel table (you'll need to change the path to the file to wherever you have stored `DuckworthLewisStern.xlsx`). I use `dplyr` functions to do the looking up. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438001/how-to-pass-column-names-into-a-function-dplyr) for more information and [this](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quo_label.html) on updates to quosures in the `rlang` package.

Then I take the output of that function and feed it into your `team2_target` function to get the target value for an example situation of 1 wicket lost and 37 overs to go.

```
library(dplyr)
DLdf <- readxl::read_xlsx("~/Downloads/DuckworthLewisStern.xlsx")

head(DLdf)

# A tibble: 6 x 11
  `Wickets Lost`    `0`    `1`    `2`    `3`    `4`    `5`    `6`   `7`    `8`    `9`
  <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Overs Left     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA     NA    
2 50              1      0.934  0.851  0.749  0.627  0.49   0.349  0.22  0.119  0.047
3 49              0.991  0.926  0.845  0.744  0.625  0.489  0.349  0.22  0.119  0.047
4 48              0.981  0.917  0.838  0.74   0.622  0.488  0.349  0.22  0.119  0.047
5 47              0.971  0.909  0.832  0.735  0.619  0.486  0.349  0.22  0.119  0.047
6 46              0.961  0.9    0.825  0.73   0.616  0.485  0.348  0.22  0.119  0.047

# a function to look up team 2's resources

get_team2_resources <- function(wickets_lost, overs_left) {

  # convert the input arguments so we can use them in the filtering and selecting below
  wl <- as_label(enquo(wickets_lost))
  ol <- as.character(overs_left)

# do the filtering to get the value we want
  DLdf %>% 
    filter(`Wickets Lost` == ol) %>% 
    select(wl) %>% 
    pull() 
}

# your existing team2_target function
team2_target = function(team1_score, team2_resources) {
  return((team1_score * team2_resources) + 1)
}

# EXAMPLE: what are the team 2 resources when 1 wicket is lost and 37 overs are left?
t2res <- get_team2_resources(wickets_lost = 1, overs_left = 37)
t2res
[1] 0.809

# what is the team 2 target when team 1 have scored 100?
team2_target(team1_score = 100, team2_resources = t2res)
[1] 81.9
```

Comment: Okay so I have hit a bit of a block here. In the secton where we try and convert the input arguments (the 'quo_name' stuff) and in the filtering, it shows up as an error on RStudio. This is the message I get: Error in quo_name(enquo(wickets_lost)) : 
  could not find function "quo_name"

Comment: Just saying, I think I got something wrong in the question I have asked. I'm going to have to reword it again (the algorithm, that is).

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `as_label` instead of `quo_name` as this is the updated `tidyeval` helper function that gets imported with `dplyr`. Do try again and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: In case you're still having problems running this code, for info I wrote it using `dplyr_0.8.1` on R 3.5.3 with RStudio 1.1.463 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.